# Game theory -- Fair bidding format for a quiz

Tags: game-theory

Let's say there is a quiz where the first round follows the pounce-and-bounce scheme:
https://quizzicallychallenged.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/what-makes-a-good-quiz/

+10 for pouncing and giving the right answer.
-5 for pouncing and giving the wrong answer.
+10 for bounce and right answer.
0 for bounce and wrong answer.

To spice up the second round, my team and I came up with an idea where participants can "gamble" with their points. We have two sub-ideas according to which the gambling is either between the participants themselves or between the quizmaster and the participants.

We tried adding details to such a scheme, however, all of them involved some players at an unfair advantage.

Any suggestions on how to properly carry this out?
Please let me know if you need any more details.